# Where are JNLP related settings stored

Tags: java, firefox, jnlp

I running a JNLP application I built from Firefox and I get these [image: dialog boxes]
On some machines, I can check the checkbox (do not ask again) and I am never prompted for these questions again. However, on other machines, even if I check the checkboxes, I get prompted with these questions again.

Where are these settings stored - are they stored in firefox or are they stored in the Java Control Panel? I want to troubleshoot this further on the machines where I getting reprompted.

Comment: I don't have that much knowledge on this, I did research on this. I found some interesting, may be it will helpful for you.  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8065891

Comment: For which dialog (left - Firefox, right - Java) the decission is not persistent?

Comment: @SubOptimal - both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first dialog box comes from firefox. The second one comes from Java Web Start.

For this firefox dialogbox

> when you thick the check box firefox stores this setting change in "handlers.json" file which is stored at profile folder. You can find profile folder at about:profiles page. Also you can modify later this setting via firefox preferences page's(about:preferences)  General -> Applications section.

For java web start

> when you select the checkbox it adds certification into ~/.java/deployment/security/sandbox.certs file and never asks again.

Comment: I know where the cached application is stored. This question is about the settings.

Comment: Sorry. I revised my answer.

Comment: Where exactly is `/.java/deployment/security/sandbox.certs` on Windows?

Comment: it should be in  %USERPROFILE%/.java/deployment/security/sandbox.certs on windows

Comment: I found it to be here - C:\Users\<username>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs